# Trying to install pymongo on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, pip

**Background Information:**

Hi there. I'm trying to get mongodb and python (2.7.8) working on my ubuntu 12.04 box. 
I've got mongodb installed and running... 
I *think I have python set up too.  Now I'm trying to install pymongo.

**Problem**

When I try to install pymongo, this is what i get:

```
me@mydev:~/Documents/Python-2.7.8$ pip install pymongo
Downloading/unpacking pymongo
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pymongo
No distributions at all found for pymongo
Storing complete log in /home/me/.pip/pip.log
me@mydev:~/Documents/Python-2.7.8$
```

The log file pip.log looks like this:  http://pastebin.com/15wv38kf

Based on the logs, tt *seems like I need to update the repositories to look for the package in a different URL... but I'm not sure what library / url to add.

**Other things I've tested / checked:**

Retrieved updated package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Proved that python 2.7.8 is installed:

```
me@medev:~/Documents/Python-2.7.8$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov  5 2014, 15:18:10) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Proved that PIP is installed:

```
me@medev:~/Documents/Python-2.7.8$ pip
Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS]

pip: error: You must give a command (use "pip help" to see a list of commands)
me@medev:~/Documents/Python-2.7.8$
```

Proved that mongodb is installed (but apparently not setup properly!):

```
me@medev:~/Documents/Python-2.7.8$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: test
2014-11-06T08:23:47.444-0500 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-11-06T08:23:47.444-0500 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
me@medev:~/Documents/Python-2.7.8$
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I tried to just install using the package manager as suggested, but that doesn't seem to work.  Please see the results at:  http://pastebin.com/V56KXzFT

Perhaps my test to prove pymongo is installed is faulty?

**EDIT 2**

I can't remember now but I think by default Ubuntu 12.0.4 comes with python 2.7.3 or something like that.  But I'm doing a course, and it requires 2.7.8.
Initially, I downloaded a zip file for python 2.7.6 and saved it in my Documents folder...
I extracted it and ran

```
./compile
make
make install
```

then I realized that I needed 2.7.8 and so I did the same thing.  Downloaded the zip ... and 
compiled. 
This is the link that I used as a reference to install 2.7.8:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu

Could this be related to the issue?

Comment: If pip is giving you a hard time, try just installing it via the Debian package `sudo apt-get install python-pymongo`.

Comment: @CasualDemon, thanks for the help.  Please see my EDIT 1 in post... it didn't work.

Comment: Are you working in a virtual environment? You will have to create it with inherited packages if it is `virtualenv --system-site-packages`.

Comment: @CasualDemon no, this is not a virtual box.. but it is a 32bit Ubuntu... i know 64bit is recommended for mongodb.  other than that, I can't think of anything else that out of the norm in my env

Comment: Not a VM, a python virtual environment. You have an odd path to a python folder `~/Documents/Python-2.7.8`, did you download a separate version of python or create a virtual environment off the main python? (Or do you have a link to the set of steps you were following)

Comment: @CasualDemon good catch. Please see Edit 2 for an attempt at retracing my steps / how i installed python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64405/discussion-between-dot-and-casualdemon).

Comment: if anyone else has some suggestions, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

"pip install pymongo" works fine on my Linux box:

```
$ sudo pip install pymongo
Downloading/unpacking pymongo
  Downloading pymongo-2.7.2.tar.gz (381kB): 381kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pymongo/setup.py) egg_info for package pymongo

Installing collected packages: pymongo
  Running setup.py install for pymongo
    building 'bson._cbson' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c bson/_cbsonmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/_cbsonmodule.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c bson/time64.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/time64.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c bson/buffer.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/buffer.o
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibson -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c bson/encoding_helpers.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/encoding_helpers.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/_cbsonmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/time64.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/buffer.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/encoding_helpers.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/bson/_cbson.so
    building 'pymongo._cmessage' extension
    < ... snip ... >

Successfully installed pymongo
Cleaning up...
```

I'd guess it failed for you because, perhaps, you first must upgrade "pip" itself.

I notice you've tried various methods of installing PyMongo, and some methods work but when you do "import pymongo" in Python it fails. Here, I guess that you have multiple version of Python installed, and that your default Python is different from the system Python for which PyMongo was installed.

Comment: hi there!  thanks for trying to help out.  So the curl command doesn't return anything.  no errors, no nothing. i just get my command prompt back immediately.  but I tried curl on http://www.google.ca and i get the page dumped on my screen...

Comment: It would seem that the problem is with the "pymongo" part of the url... because when i do a "curl https://pypi.python.org/simple".. it works.  Maybe I need to specify which version I want when I do the pip install pymongo??

Comment: Hmm. PyMongo installs fine for me:

Comment: yes, that's correct. i did manually install 2.7.6 and then 2.7.8...I think by default, ubuntu 12.04 comes with 2.7.3 if i remember correctly.  i guess i shouldn't have installed manually?  the thing is, i'm doing an online course and i have to have 2.7.8.  any suggestions?  Please see "EDIT 2" in my post..